# How to redirect requests to the "public/" directory using .htaccess file while the laravel project is in a subdirectory

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess

my directory structure looks like this:

```
/
├─ index.html
├─ .htaccess
├── backend/
│   ├── public/
│   │   ├── index.php
```

My goal is to set up the .htaccess file in the root directory so that any URL like `example.com/backend` is redirected to `example.com/backend/public` or in another word `example.com/backend/index.php` is redirected to `example.com/backend/public/index.php`. The `backend` directory contains a Laravel project that serves as an API, and I need to access it via url like `example.com/backend/anylaravelroute`.

Here is my current .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
    
    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ /backend/public/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The issue I'm facing is that while this .htaccess configuration successfully redirects requests to `/backend/public/index.php`, the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in PHP still contain the path with `/backend/`. As a result, Laravel handles routes incorrectly and returns a 404 error. For example, `example.com/backend/api` returns a 404 error, while `example.com/api` works but not what i want, the `APP_URL` in laravel is set to `example.com/backend`and i'm using laravel 10.10.

I cannot change the directory structure by moving the public directory outside of /backend/ due to specific constraints. Additionally, I don't have control over the Apache configuration, solving this issue will prevent any direct access to files in the backend directory because all requests will be redirected to backend/public so will not cause security problems.
Now, I need to configure the .htaccess file to achieve the desired behavior. There is one alternative solution, which involves using symlinks, but it may introduce other problems. Therefore, it's preferable to address this using .htaccess.